# Why does my console application give a Win32 exception for the machine type when deployed?

Tags: c#, x86, console-application, 64-bit

I created a simple console application using Visual C# Express Edition 2010. The application does some simple data preparation, and then calls Process.Start to run curl from the command prompt to submit the data to the web service. I can compile and run the application successfully.

However, when I deploy it to my test server (simply copying the compiled files over) and attempt to run it there, I get the following exception message (I have it dumped to the console window):

> The image file %1 is valid, but is for a machine type other than the
>   current machine.

What would be causing this message? I can't change my default configuration to specify a different architecture, and I believe it defaults to x86, which should run on a 64 bit platform just fine.

What would be giving me this error?

Comment: Try compiling with "CPU - any".

Comment: What OS is the dev machine and what OS is the Test Server? 32bit will run on 64bit, but 64bit wont run on 32bit. So if your dev machine Win7 64bit and you're deploying to say 32 Win Server2003, it will fail with default compilation options.

Comment: @ChrisF I can't seem to find the drop down to change architecture in C# Express like I can do in Visual Web Developer Express, even with the Advanced Settings turned on. Where would I find them?

Comment: @rism Agreed on the directional. I'm pretty sure the server is running x64, and my dev machine is Win7 x64, but I guess it would be easier if I could find the CPU setting. Is there a chance it could be related to the curl executable I have packaged?

Comment: Does your server have WOW64 disabled?

Comment: If you create a setup program for this app, instead of just copying the files, the setup.exe bootstrapper should detect missing dependencies and install them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How would I know of WOW64 is disabled? Is there a command I can run?

Comment: @BobHorn That does have a lot of potential, since the executable will need to remain on the server for the occasional run. I'll have to look into that.